# Will code after setState() in React be run?

Tags: reactjs, setstate

Trying to understand the workings of setState() in React. My question is this.

If I have a function where one of the lines is setState(), will code lines AFTER this line still be run before the rerendering? For instance, in the code bellow,

```
foo(value) {
     this.setState({stateValue: value});
     console.log("Stuff after setState");
}
```

In that code, is the console.log guaranteed to run? It runs when I test it, but I'm uncertain if this is just because React hasn't had time to re-render yet. Can I expect code after this.setState() to run?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

`setState` is `asynchronous` function and just like any asynchronous function is being passed on to the event loop, `setState` also is passed on to the event loop and any code after it will execute seemlessly.

Once the setState method has completed executing, it will trigger the render method, which is when React will work on the document render.

Answer (score 3):

Let's see the [setState documentation](https://reactjs.org/docs/react-component.html#setstate)

> Think of setState() as a request rather than an immediate command to update the component
>
> React does not guarantee that the state changes are applied immediately

Think of it as `setTimeout(function test() {...}, 0);` a message will be added to the queue, the `test` function will not be fired until all the stack is empty. You can find more information on the [EventLoop documentation](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/EventLoop)